# The domain of $f(x)=x^{m/n}$ compared to $f(x)=\sqrt[\frac{n}{m}]{x}$

Tags: calculus, functions

When I calculate the domain of $f(x)=x^{m/n}$ or $f(x)=\sqrt[\frac{n}{m}]{x}$ given n is even, I know that both functions are defined for $x\ge0$.
The problem I faced during solving my math homework, is what is the domain of each function mentioned above when n is not an even number.
I thought the domain of both function are similar and defined for all real numbers.
 However, when I checked myself in the answers and with my math teacher it occured to me that $f(x)=\sqrt[\frac{n}{m}]{x}$ is defined for all real numbers, while $f(x)=x^{m/n}$ is defined only for $x\ge0$.
Why is that?
For example, here is a link to geogebra of two graphs- $f(x)=x^{1/5}$ and $g(x)=\sqrt[{5}]{x}$ compared 
[the two graphs comapred- example](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/xwtkgb8q)
Thanks!

Comment: Well , $\sqrt[\frac{b}{a}]{x} = x^{\frac{a}{b}}$

Comment: What ? The comment ?

Comment: I have answers for these excersies and my math teacher told me so

Comment: If $\sqrt[a]{x} = x^{\frac{1}{a}}$, what I said can also be right, right ?

Comment: Yes I'm asking about n not even

Comment: It is impossible to tell without knowing your definitions. In mathematics normally, $x^{m/n}$ is **the definition** of $\sqrt[\frac{n}{m}]{x}$, so it is impossible for them to have different domains.

Comment: @preferred_anon I edited the post take a look at the link I posted

Comment: @MichalOzeri It seems that geogebra's definition of surds excludes negative numbers. It does not have to, because $x^{1/5}$ and $\sqrt[5]{x}$ are equal, and can be defined for any real number. But you get to choose the domain.

Comment: To be clear, the expression $x^{1/5}$ or $\sqrt[5]{x}$ by itself does not define a function. You specify the domain (and range) independently. Both $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{\ge 0}$ are possible domains for this expression.

Answer (score 1):

This is how Mathematica interprets it. By the way for $a$ in $\sqrt[a]{x}$ it accepts only non-zero integers (positive or negative).

[image]

Comment: What about the comments I posted below the question ?

Comment: Should that work well ?